# How to load data from a Firestore query into a variable at the global scope for later use

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Like my question title says, I'd like to load a firestore query result into a variable at my global scope for later use.

I want to use the value later in a dynamic listener and I don't want to have to re-query it again and again.

I've tried looking on google for a simple solution. I've already tried implementing my own solution with promise, callbacks, and async await but to no avail.

This is from the github documentation that shows how to do what I want, but without a query.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/tips/index.js

```js
const heavyComputation = () => {
  // Multiplication is more computationally expensive than addition
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  return numbers.reduce((t, x) => t * x);
};

const functionSpecificComputation = heavyComputation;
const fileWideComputation = lightComputation;

// [START functions_tips_scopes]
// [START run_tips_global_scope]
// Global (instance-wide) scope
// This computation runs at instance cold-start
const instanceVar = heavyComputation();
```

Here is my own attempt

```js
const getNBAScoreKey = () => {


        return new Promise(resolve => {
            scoresRef.onSnapshot(nbaScoreKeySnapshot => {
                console.log("the value inside the score key: " + nbaScoreKeySnapshot.data()["FantScores"]);

                resolve(nbaScoreKeySnapshot.data());
            });

        });

    }
```

I expect the variable to be an object with the data, but instead whatever implementation I try I get 'undefined'.

Comment: When data() returns undefined, it means that there is no document referred to by `scoresRef`.  https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html#data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set variable in global scope and reassign it's value in `scoresRef.onSnapshot` but If you are trying to access this value immediately without waiting for data to be fetched from database, of course you will get undefined because data not fetched yet.

So in your case you have to use observable design pattern, by using lib like [rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) or implementing it yourself,

Observable lets you define an variable and subscribe on value change events.

Simple observer implementation

```
let observer = {

    value: {} ,
    subscribers: [] ,
    subscribe: function (cb ) { this.subscribers.push(cb)} , 
    notify: function (data) { this.value = data ; this.subscribers.forEach( s => s(data);}

}
```

to subscribe on value changes, you have to call observer.subscribe and pass callback function to be fired on data changes

```
observer.subscribe((data)=> { console.log('first', data ) } ) // first subscriber
observer.subscribe((data)=> { console.log('sec', data ) } ) // sec subscriber
```

// to notify subscriber that value has been changed

```
observer.notify(123)
```

the output will be

```
first 123123
sec 123123
```

Your case you have to subscribe first any where on that observer

```
observer.subscribe((data)=> { 
  console.log('I got some data from firestore', data );

  // Do some stuff
} );
```

and just add notify in your fetch function

```
const getNBAScoreKey = () => {


        return new Promise(resolve => {
            scoresRef.onSnapshot(nbaScoreKeySnapshot => {
                console.log("the value inside the score key: " + nbaScoreKeySnapshot.data()["FantScores"]);
                let data = nbaScoreKeySnapshot.data();
                observer.notify(data);
                resolve(data);
            });

        });

    }
```

also you can get data in any time by calling `observer.data` will return the latest data

**make sure you have defined observer in global scope, or on separate file and export observer variable then import that file anywhere the data will be shared**

Comment: ok I will try to implement and let you know. But I still don't understand why my example is different than the github 'heavyComputation' example. In that example, at cold start the function does heavy computation and returns a value that can be used later. Why is my example different?

Comment: Does promise not wait to resolve before continuing execution?

Comment: It's all about that code is synchronous or asynchronous even if this code is a heavy computation, javascript handle async code by callbacks instead of blocking the code, if you have an async code like promises or calling web service or database javascript engine will not wait for data to be fetched it will run the other code which below this async call and fire callback when that async call finished so you have to pass callback function to be executed when it finished, please check [this](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/how-node-and-javascript-handle-asynchronous-functions-7feb9fc8a610)

Comment: Many thanks, I think I understand and will try to implement. Last question, I know async/await is blocking (right?), but would that work in this case?

Comment: For instance, use async/await to wait for the database to return the value at cold start, then proceed with the code below?

Comment: Yes it will work, but make sure that async await will block code only in async function scope , if you have an `async function x () { await fetchData ; console.log(1) console.log(2) } x(); console.log(3);` the output will be 3,1,2 because log 3 is not inside async function so if you want to use the data outside async function it will be undefined also

Comment: ooohh, that helps a lot, I didn't know that. Thanks. It seems like rx is better for my problem